# Can you turn on/off keyboard backlight using Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, keyboard, autohotkey, backlight

I tried `AHK` to turn-off the keyboard's backlight but it's failed. As I understood, there's no way to send Function keys (FN) in `AHK`.

I found there is a software called `PredatorSense` by Asus, it can turn on/off the backlight, so I think there is another way to achieve it.

Any idea if PowerShell could achieve this or any another possible mothed?

Comment: Does the PredatorSense software expose an API?

Comment: I believe it does not, I can't find any SDK or API related to PredatorSense

Comment: I suspect that you would have to look at the driver for the keyboard.

Comment: Would you mind briefly explain how do I do that? I'm an 'average' programmer :)

Comment: Beats me off the top of my head, but that is the direction I would start researching.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for the head start :)